# How to match presence at least one of several optional groups?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression with three "zero or one" groups, simply put: `(\d\s)?(\w\s)?(\D\s)?` and I want the regex to do not match if a string does not contain any of these groups.

Detailed:

1. `"0 a x"` — good string, match;
2. `"a x "`, `"0 x "`, `"0 a "` — good string, match;
3. `"0"`, `"a"`, `"x"` — good string, match;
4. `""` (empty string) — ugly, do not match.

Is there are a way to do this via regex? Or only with a support of my programming language?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?!\s*$)(\d*\s*)(\w*\s*)([^\d\r\n]*\s*)$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K20rVm/3)**

OR

[`^(?! *$)(\d* *)(\w* *)([^\d\r\n]* *)$`](https://regex101.com/r/K20rVm/4)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?!\s*$)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the string is not empty
- `(\d*\s*)` - matches 0+ digits followed by 0+ whitespaces and capture it in Group 1
- `(\w*\s*)` - matches 0+ word characters followed by 0+ whitespaces and capture it in Group 2
- `([^\d\r\n]*\s*)` - matches 0+ non-digits followed by 0+ whitespaces and capture it in Group 3
- `$` - asserts the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent advice, I did not consider using of a lookahead.